# Vectorizing a recurrence equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a recurrence equation:

```
a(i+1)=a(i)+(((b(i)+b(i+1))*(c(i+1)-c(i)))/(d(i)+d(i+1)));
```

I have the required vectors `b`,`c`, and `d` and they all have the same length. I can assume that `a(1)=0`.

Generally, I always do this using a loop but since the data is too large, it takes a considerable amount of time. I was wondering if there is a way to vectorize `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I have got the answer. After doing a bit of math on paper, I get this:

```
a=cumsum([a(1) ((b(1:end-1)+b(2:end)).*diff(c))./(d(1:end-1)+d(2:end))]);
```

Comment: Looks good. You should check on a small piece of code if the vectorized version gives the same result as the loop though.