# Vectorization of self-dependant MATLAB loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I am pretty new to matlab and am trying to understand vectorization. I am usually able to find a way to vectorize my code, but this time is different. Note that e() and f() aren't function calls but arrays, a(i,j) is a matrix. The problem here is that the value of e(i) depends on the value of e(i-1). Same thing also happens for f(i). Is there a way to vectorize this loop in order to gain speed?

The function takes A a tridiagonal symmetric matrix, b the solution to the Ax=b linear system and outputs sol: the solution to the system. The code works as is, i just want to make it quicker where possible. Hope the additional details help.

```
function [sol] = MySolTridiagDirect(A,b)
   %Adds 2 slack variables
   a = [zeros(size(A,1),1),A,zeros(size(A,1),1)];
   %Adds solutions to slack variables 
   b = [zeros(1,size(b,2));b;zeros(1,size(b,2))];

   e = NaN(size(A,1)+1,1);
   f = NaN(size(A,1)+1,1);
   x = NaN(size(A,1)+1,1);

   e(1) = 0;
   f(1) = 0;
   x(1) = 0;

   for i=2:size(f,1)
       e(i) = (-a(i-1,i+1)) / (a(i-1,i-1)*e(i-1,1) + a(i-1,i));
       f(i) = (b(i) - a(i-1,i-1)*f(i-1)) / (a(i-1,i-1)*e(i-1,1) + a(i-1,i));    
   end
   %% Solver for variable 'x' (solution)
   x(end) = f(end);
   for i=size(f,1)-1:-1:2
      x(i) = e(i)*x(i+1) + f(i);
   end
   sol = x(2:end,:);
end
```

Comment: Do you need all values e(i) and f(i) or is only the last value of interest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vectorizing a recurrence equation in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367100/vectorizing-a-recurrence-equation-in-matlab)

Comment: @m.s.: I don't see a possibility to apply that solution here. Think it's a different problem.

Comment: @Daniel i only need the last value for both e(i) and f(i) !

Comment: @Fredaugermorin, sorry, deleted my answer. It assumed that you use the *old* values on the right hand side. But this is exactly your problem: you need the *new* `e` and `f` for the next point. I'm not sure any of it can be vectorized...

Comment: What are the exact sizes of the input arrays? Or let's say `A` is `M x N` sized, then what are the sizes of the other input arrays w.r.t. `M` and `N`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak yeah this is what i am starting to figure out. Thank you though.

Comment: @Divakar A is always NxN, i will edit with my entire code leading to the loop

Comment: So how about `sol=linsolve(A,b)`?;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak This is an assignment question, we are asked to create a Cholesky Decomposition function (similar to matlab's chol()) by ourselves from scratch, but the input matrix are always tridiagonal symetric matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem can not be vectorized in a traditional way, I did not find any possibility to simplify the code and doing so increase the performance by a factor of ~2

```
a2=diag(a,2);
a0=diag(a,0);
a1=diag(a,1);

for i=2:size(f,1)
    e(i) = (-a2(i-1)) / (a0(i-1)*e(i-1) + a1(i-1));
    f(i) = (b(i) - a0(i-1)*f(i-1)) / (a0(i-1)*e(i-1) + a1(i-1));    
end
```

To find a vectorisation, I used the symbolic toolbox to display the full formula to calculate e(i) only using e(1), but I failed to see any possibilities to implement these calculations in a vectorized manner. If you look at the formulas, there are more and more nested brackets involved:

```
n=4;
f=sym('f',[n,1]);
e=sym('e',[n,1]);
a1=sym('a1',[n,1]);
a0=sym('a0',[n,1]);
a2=sym('a2',[n,1]);
b=sym('b',[n,1]);

for i=2:size(f,1)
    e(i) = simplify((-a2(i-1)) / (a0(i-1)*e(i-1) + a1(i-1)));
    f(i) = simplify((b(i) - a0(i-1)*f(i-1)) / (a0(i-1)*e(i-1) + a1(i-1)));    
end
```

The only possibilities I know to evaluate such formulas are recursion and for-loops. As for-loops are much faster than recursion in matlab, there is probably no better way.

Comment: Thank you, i was looking into recursion ATM as i did not know how fast and efficient it was in Matlab. I'm used to lower level languages and therefore vectorization is a concept i have to familiarize myself with. Thanks for your answer and time.